# Labeling Many-to-many relationships ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, labeling, relates

please i have Many-to-many relationships in arcMap like : 
[image]

and i want to show labels in parcel  using ArcMap 10 :

- field to show is : Zoning and Name
  -

do you have any idea how to do it ?

- **Edit**
  -

[image]

Comment: so when you label parcel PIN=4, should the label be "Sam" or "Joe" or "Sam and Joe"?

Comment: Can you include a graphic of how you would like to see the parcel with PIN=4 labelled, please?

Comment: @Roland , PolyGeo  Sam ,Joe

Answer (score 1):

this is [not possible](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31030) as such

What you could do is concatenate all the field values for the related tables on one single line, then you join the new field to your table and you can use it for labelling.

Note that the data shown on your image could be aggregated in order to make one-to-many relationship, but maybe your original dataset is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

based @Abdel's edit, I think the type of answer recommended by @radouxju is the key. It's kind of messy, but that's the nature of this problem (one-to-many relations resulting in lists where each row can be of a variable length).

Another alternative you may want to investigate if all you want is to display is to do something like make a map of polygon centroids, [`addXYCoordinates`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//001700000032000000) to that featureclass, transfer this XY info over to your `Owner` table, and then generate a new point feature class (which will replicate a polygon centroid once for each occurrence of that polygon's `Own` id in the table). This point featureclass might even be useful for analysis, but that's another question...